# OS X App, Using HTML pages for Help System, Can HTML links be altered to work inside the app?

Tags: html, webview, osx-lion

OS X App, Using HTML pages for Help System, Can you help me?

I have Eight Web pages. Each two column Page has the same eight link sidebar menu.
These eight pages work in Safari once I load the first "landing" page.

I have a Window with a WebView that display correctly when the following code runs to load
this "landing" page:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"HungryMe" withExtension:@"html"];
NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
...
}
```

A fragment of the HTML follows:

```
<div class="sidebar1">
 <ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="file:///DataDisk/Cocoa/HungryMeHelp/HungryMe.html">1.Getting Started</a></li>
...
```

The eight link html  "menu" obviously does not work as is, my Question is:

Do I have to put eight buttons on the Window next to the WebView, each button 
corresponding to  a different page, displaying Help or
can I somehow alter the links so that the "HTML menu" will work inside the app? Or
maybe I am just looking at this incorrectly?

Many Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found the answer. There are special URLs called Apple Help URLs , URLs that can be used to find files inside the app's Bundle. I am now using these Help URLS in conjunction with Help anchors. The anchor is put in the target file.
    
Then display page:

```
<a href='help:anchor=topic1_page bookID=theBookID'>1.Topic #1</a>
```

See Help Book Docs.